# WPF data grid not updating

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi There seem to be different reasons for that and I tried a few of them but it does not seem to work.

My scenario is that:
I add an item to the collection linked as a `datasource` to the `grid` and then run a command line or some other code.

**The problem**

The first row shows up but after that I can add rows but they don't show up in the `grid`.

my code:

**View**

```
    <DataGrid Margin="5" Name="progress"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CanUserAddRows="False" 
        SelectionMode="Extended" 
        SelectionUnit="Cell" 
        Height="150"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="370" Binding="{Binding Action}" IsReadOnly="True" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Success}" IsReadOnly="True" />
           </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

**Code behind**

```
ObservableCollection<StepResult> stepResults;
stepResults = new ObservableCollection<StepResult>();
progress.DataContext = stepResults;
private void Updater_StepStart(object sender, ScriptInterpreter.Events.StepEventArguments e)
{
     stepResults.Add(new StepResult
     {
        Action = e.StepName,
        Success = true
      });
}
```

What I tried to so far:

```
progress.UpdateLayout();
progress.ItemsSource = null;
progress.ItemsSource = stepResults;
```

Nothing working tho :(

Comment: If all runs in the UI thread, the UI will not update until it has an idle phase. If you need to run it inside the UI thread (and not a background thread) you can still use the `Dispatcher` to invoke an idle action for the UI to update.

Comment: "then run a command line or some other code". What does this mean? Show your *full* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try setting the ObservableCollection as as Property and binding the ItemsSource to it.
Something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding stepResult}"/>
```

And the Code-Behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<StepResult> _stepResults;
public ObservableCollection<StepResult> StepResults
{
    get { return _stepResults; }
    set
    {
        if (_stepResult == value)
            return;
        _stepResults = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And settings the DataContext like this:

```
progress.DataContext = this;
```

This should work. At least it almost always did for me.

Comment: Have you tried to set the DataSource after filling the Collection? Do you generate new instances of the Collection?

Comment: I tryed to set the ItemsSource again with no luck. I do not create a new instance of the collection

Comment: Has StepResult the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? Or try setting the ItemsSource to another Collection and not null. I have heard, that WPF sometimes has a Problem with setting the Source to null.

Comment: No helping either. Can't belve that that is so hard :). I am new to WPF but seem a pretty trivial task.

Comment: Then I have no idea. And I can't replicate it because this works for me most of the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149726/discussion-between-lightlike-and-jester).